# including a javascript file at the end of the file doesn't work for some functions

Tags: javascript, html

In my file, a have many dom elements and an external javascript file that has some functions to manage events. The problem is that when i include the `functions.js` file at the end of my main file:

```
            <script src="functions.js"></script>
```

That works for some elements but not for others. So i move that at the top of my file, and now it works for some elements but not the other either.

It doesn't works means that i got such error in the web console:

```
ReferenceError: oneOfMyFunctions is not defined
```

What is the best place to put that include? Thanx in advance.

**EDIT:**

In my html file (the main file), i did this:

```
        <script>
                window.onload = function(){

        // start calling your function eg. functions.j();
        myFunction();

   };

     </script>
```

Still get the same issue.

Comment: some code somewhere in the file might be trying to call oneOfMyFunctions. The javascript engine executes js in the order it appears on the page.

Comment: So? this is confusing, i don't know where to include the file: the top and the end both doesn't resolve it.

Comment: The problem arises because as the document is constructed, any tags calling those functions actually call the tag **before** the function has been loaded since it's at the bottom of the document. Use the document.onload() to avoid that problem, since document.onload() is called AFTER the document is done loading.  An easy way is to make a function called onDocLoad() and put all of your other function calls inside of it, and then use document.onload(onDocLoad()) or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `JavaScript` file anywhere in page. But you should use `window.onload` method to start execution of your code.

```
<script>

  window.onload = function(){

        // start calling your function eg. functions.j();
   };

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, assuming i have two functions in `functions.j`: `function1` and `function2`. How would it be like?

Comment: @Malloc can you show your code? window.onload will make sure that all required resources are loaded before start of execution.

Comment: If i will do this, the function is executed and not just loaded.

Comment: What do yo mean by function loading? you can load js files from any where. but you should start execution after window.onload.

Comment: in my main file, shall i do this: `window.onload = function(){

        function1(); function2();
        
   };`

Comment: yes, You can do that. or you can write it inside html page(preferred ).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17364/discussion-between-shusl-and-malloc)

Comment: @Malloc, unline some other languages, Javascript has _no_ issues with one function being parsed (parsed, not executed), calling another function which is not defined until later. There's no need for "forward declarations", and mutual functions that call each other work just fine. As long as you don't try to _execute_ a function before all the functions it calls are defined, everything works fine. (Note these comments about no-need-for-forward-function-declarations are specific to Javascript -- not every computer language is like this.)

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke the function before its loaded, it doesn't know what to do. There are two solutions to this:

1. Use the window.onload option (or jquery $(document).ready(function(){ ... });
2. make the function call after you load the scripts.